# average call duration in last 24 hours ZendFramework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have some trouble with an MYSQL query in ZendFramework , I want to get average call duration in last 24 hours and query like this :

```
SELECT AVG(duration) FROM table1 where calldate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR;
```

Here the code from my ZendFramework:

**Models:**

```
<?php
class Model_Cdr extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'table1';
    protected $_schema = 'db1';
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$callModel= new Model_Cdr();
  $select_tot_24 = $callModel->fetchAll($callModel->select()->where("calldate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" ));
  echo $avg_24 = AVG($select_tot_24);
```

and also I've tried this :

```
$callModel= new Model_Cdr();
 $avg_24_1 = $callModel->fetchAll("SELECT AVG(duration WHERE calldate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it:

```
$callModel = new Model_Cdr();
$select = $callModel->select()
            ->from($callModel, array('average' => 'AVG(duration)'))
           ->where('calldate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');

  $row = $callModel->fetchRow($select);
  echo 'Average time: ' . $row->average;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *Zend_Db_Table_Select*:

```
$callModel = new Model_Cdr();
$select = $callModel->select()
                    ->from('table1', array('average' => 'AVG(duration)'))
                    ->where('calldate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)');

$row = $callModel->fetchRow($select);
echo 'Average time: ' . $row->average;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found was occurred. I've edited my question. please review this